# Function python list (zip)

Tags: python, list, function, zip

This are 2 lists:

```
a= [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
b= ["Python", "Java"]
```

So i want this result:

```
X = [[1,2,3], "python"]
Y = [[4,5,6], "Java"]
```

It must become a function: e.g.:

```
def zipp (a,b):
  for same in zip(a,b):
     return (i)

print (zipp(a,b))
```

But, when i replace the return (i) in the function by print (i), it prints what i want... but unfortunately it only returns 1 of the 2. How can i return both?

Comment: it must be return (same) excuses

Comment: Why write a function at all? What's wrong with `X,Y = zip(a,b)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
>>> def zipp (a,b):
...    return [[x,y] for x, y in zip(a, b)]

>>> zipp(a, b)
[[[1, 2, 3], 'Python'], [[4, 5, 6], 'Java']]
```

> It must become a function...

Note that you use `zip` directly, without defining any extra functions:

```
>>> print(list([x, y] for x, y in zip(a, b)))
[[[1, 2, 3], 'Python'], [[4, 5, 6], 'Java']]
```

Comment: Bit confusing for anyone new to python to see so many `a`'s and `b`'s . Think it would be clearer if you renamed some if them

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not understand how the function works.
When you call a function, if the function returns a value, the loops will not continue. The `i` are not simultaneously returned.